# Set list item visibility as hidden by default

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I need to set list item as hidden till I share this item, is this possible in SharePoint list?
I can stop sharing an item to a specific group, through "Share"->"Advanced option"-> "Stop Sharing" menu, after this item become invisible to that group. But I need to hide all items by default and need to show items to group after sharing this.

Comment: Can you please share more information, on how do you add list item? Like do you add via OOB forms or some Code? Do you have any hook on items?

Comment: I am adding list item using normal "New" button click.

Comment: I am adding list item using normal "New" button click. My scenario is, Admin will add a list of 'Projects" to a list. The persons under each Project group should only see this "Project" item after admin sharing this item o that group. Until sharing it should be invisible.

Comment: I think you have to Break Role Assignment Inheritance on current item before save. You need to develop your own custom new item form for it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185013(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: What about enabling the approval process so the item will only be shown to the user when it is published?

Comment: You could remove that's group's access to the list. Then when new items are added, they inherit the security of the list. When you want the group to be able see the item, break inheritance on that item, then give Read access (or whatever) to the group, then they will be able to see that item.